# special characters from git to eclipse

Tags: java, git

So I am cloning some java files from git to eclipse. There are special characters like Ü è. letters you would see in the Spanish language that java normally does not like. When I open up the project in java it turns them into the square with the ? in the middle of it and java complains about it saying there is a special character problem. It wouldn't be that big of a problem but I'm doing it for work and there are A LOT of code and go through and a lot of special characters. Anything I can do about this to either make java like it or not change the characters when I go from git to eclipse?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181068/6309 help?

Comment: I don't think so its because when I download from git it just auto changes it to the ? in the square

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that when you say "I open up the project in java" you actually mean opening the project in Eclipse:)

You need to do two things: first figure out what the file encoding is, second change your settings so Eclipse would use that encoding. [Figuring out the encoding can be troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows). With a git remote repository on Unix the obvious guess would be UTF-8, with Windows UTF-16 would also come into my mind as a possibility. In worst case you can always open your file in a hex editor and check how are your special characters actually encoded. After that [making Eclipse use that encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse) is easy. (And you may consider [changing it only for this special project of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494326/setting-text-file-encoding-per-eclipse-project).)